# Does the DJI Phantom 4 advanced has the fisheye effect on taking videos from above?

Tags: distortion, fisheye

I make research on transportation systems. I'm going to use a Dji Phantom 4 Advanced in order to take videos from above and then I will georeference multiple frames. Should I take into account the ''fisheye effect''? Does the specific UAV produce this effect?

Comment: I don't see how this is off topic. People use drones to take photos. Those photos may or may not suffer the fisheye effect. Whether or not you may have to correct for it is of course applicable to still photography.

Comment: I agree with Hueco, but still -1 for the lack of basic research (tech specs and/or footage/photos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The tech specs say it features a 24mm equiv. lens](https://www.dji.com/phantom-4-adv/info#specs) - it does not mention "fish eye" anywhere, and since fish-eye lenses usually are ultrawide (around 16mm), this also seems to indicate a rectilinear lens.

[This random test footage](https://youtu.be/3VoUZ8AbxPo?t=136) seems to indicate that it does not have a fisheye lens, too.

**You may have to take into account light distortions - however, you will have to do that with all lenses that are not [industrial-grade aerial lenses](https://industrial.phaseone.com/lenses.aspx).**

Comment: Me: gets excited about aerial lenses. Oh, that’s phase one you linked to? I’ll just go be poor over here.

Comment: @Hueco [Is Hasselblad okay?](https://www.hasselblad.com/industrial/) ;-) Hold back your GAS!

Comment: Actually, a local guy is selling a RB67 for $400 in my area...going to be checking that out this weekend :-)

Comment: @Hueco Sounds nice! Especially for guinea pig shots ;-) (If that comment did not make sense to you, I apologize - but IIRC, we talked about guinea shootings in some other comments ;-) )

Comment: Indeed, I do recall. We actually found a new home for our boys - it was getting too much to handle with a newborn, two cats, and a fish. It was tough, and we'll probably adopt more in the future - but for now, I'll be puttin' it to use on the baby photos

Comment: @Hueco Congratulations! Though am a tiny bit sad about giving away the guineas. ;-)

Comment: Yea, it was a rough day - my wife and I both teared up a bit. But, they get much more floor time now. We had them in a 2'x4' cage, but they really love to stretch their legs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90353/discussion-between-hueco-and-flolilolilo).